# Ubuntu Jammy 22.04 double click on chrome sometimes ended with move pointer

Tags: 22.04, maximized, doubleclick

Just upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04. Would like to double click to maximize the chrome window, but most of the time it will show a move cursor instead. See photo below. [image] Have to keep trying multiple times before able to maximize it. Do you know how to get back the previous behaviour?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue here. Did you get any solution for that? Not only Chrome is behaving differently, but the Ubuntu dock auto-hide is weird as well, but only when Chrome is maximized.

Comment: @Luciano nope, still waiting for answer...

Comment: I noticed the app Flameshot is failing as well, after that Ubuntu update.

Comment: Please upvote this chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1439861

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this workaround: https://ossmalta.eu/workaround-chrome-chromium-double-click-maximize-not-working-in-ubuntu-22-04/

From the two alternatives it teaches you, I going to transcribe here just the simple one:

1. Log off or restart your system
2. Choose the user to login
3. When it asks you for the password open the settings (right-bottom engine), and change it to "Ubuntu on Xorg".
4. Type the password
5. All done! It must work now!

I don't know what are the drawbacks of using "Ubuntu on Xorg" instead of the default one.

Comment: I think this also one of the suggested solution for the issue of gnome screen video recorder unable to record correctly. Will try it when got chance!

Comment: It fixed every issue I had after Ubuntu update, like Chrome double click maximization, Dock autohide, and Flameshot (screenshotter).

Comment: You are definitively right about it! This fixes it!

Comment: The far less intrusive workaround from the article you linked is to right click the Chrome title bar and select "Use system title bar and borders".

Comment: Ah, this is a pretty significant suggestion. This uses Xorg as the Window display server instead of the newer Wayland, which is the new standard (but is experiencing some growing pains). I personally wouldn't use this solution (since Wayland has some bugfixes that I like) so I'd go with the other answer, personally.

Comment: This switches your entire desktop window manager to Xorg, which is somewhat outdated but still working and widely used I guess in the linux world. You may encounter other issues with other applications, if you do, remember to try reverting this.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the settings from the 3dot menu of your chrome.

On the search bar at the top type in:

`Use system`

This will highlight `Use system title bar and borders`

Eanble it, and you are set.

Comment: Ah, this is an actual fix! Nice! It sucks that it takes up a bit more screen real estate, but I'll that.

Comment: Nice! this also shows the full title of the current tab at the top, at the mentioned cost of taking some more screen estate. Seems like the best workaround for now and nice to know this feature.